# Assign CX public value struct contents of native C++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, c++-cx

If I have two structs like this:

```
struct A {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;
}

public value struct B {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;
}
```

What's the best way to convert from A to B (and vice versa). Can I do something like: `B struct_b = static_cast<B>(A{1,2,3,4})`?

Answer (score 0):

The supported way to do this is via conversion operators:

```
struct A;

public value struct B {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;

internal:
    operator A();
};

struct A {
    float a;
    float b;
    float c;
    float d;

    operator B()
    {
        return B{ a, b, c, d };
    }
};

B::operator A()
{
    return A{ a, b, c, d };
}
```

Note that Intellisense might complain about `operator A()` with a red squiggly and a tool-tip about "public non-data members" but you can ignore it and the code will compile. The `internal` keywords means "`public` inside C++ but not exposed as part of metadata in the WinMD."